# PHP and AJAX internal 500 error

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have a strange problem, when I send data in POST with AJAX in JQuery to query SQL in php and push the data in array, the server return 500 error.

This the php file :

```
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
$objConn=new ConnectionDB();
$connection=$objConn->ConnecteDB();
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $dataRetourn=$_POST["test"]; 
    $debut=$_POST['debut'];
    $fin=$_POST['fin'];
    $proute=array();
    $i=0;
    $i=0;
    foreach ($dataRetourn as $data){
        $imei = $data["aniImei"];
        $requete="SELECT latitude, longitude, dateHeure
              FROM anilog
              WHERE anilog.imei='$imei' and dateHeure BETWEEN '$debut' AND 
              '$fin'
              ORDER BY dateHeure ASC";
        $resultat1=mysqli_query($connection,$requete);
        while($donnees=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat1)){
             $dataRetourn[$i]["path"][]=$donnees;
        }
        $i=$i+1;
    }
echo json_encode($dataRetourn);
mysql_close($connection);
```

My query AJAX :

```
var options = {
url: "js/controller/getParcours.php",
dataType: "text",
type: "POST",
data: { test: parcours, debut : datep.debut, fin: datep.fin}
};

$.ajax(options).done(function(data){console.log(JSON.parse(data));});
```

PS: the PHP version on the server is the 5.3

And the variable parcours in query AJAX is $dataretourn in php script and it's an array of object

Comment: You are mxing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` in the last line `mysql_close($connection);`

Comment: You should really upgrade to a current version of PHP. PHP 5.3 reached its end of life more than 3 years ago.

Comment: Also, you should [validate](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) the input data.

Comment: Your code seems sloppy. Not written with care. Why two lines with `$i=0;`? No error checking. Weird indentation and spacing. No comments. Etc. Etc. The reason your code doesn't work is because you don't seem to care.

Comment: It seems like you copied the code blindly..! @Kevin Breda

Answer (score 3):

A HTTP 500 error code always means there is something wrong with your serverside code, your case being your PHP script. This may either be a syntax error or a bug.

You should be able to find more information in your server log, if you are using nginx this would be `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and if you are using apache, this would be `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (unless otherwise specified in your VirtualHost/site configuration).

**However it is highly discouraged to use PHP 5.3 since it is deprecated**, more information here: [PHP version lifetime](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)